# Shell script to check if file A or B is presen in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

How to check if either file-A or file-B is present in a directory?

The script to check the existence of file-A is as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

if [ -e "/home/usr/file-A.txt" ]; then 
     echo "INFO: file-A is present" 
else 
     echo "INFO: file-A is not present"
fi
```

What are the required modifications?

Comment: Similarly using perl script I want check if a files A or B are present in a directory.
If none, either or both files are present in the directory, it should be informed to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [ -e "/home/usr/file-A.txt" ] || [ -e "/home/usr/file-B.txt" ]; then 
     echo "File present" 
else 
     echo "Not present"
fi
```

Just add `|| [ -e "/home/usr/file-B.txt" ]` with the `if` implementing OR.

Using perl to check none, either or both.

```
SWITCH: {
        if (-e "home/usr/file-A.txt" && -e "home/usr/file-B.txt") { print "Both files present"; last SWITCH; }
        if (-e "home/usr/file-A.txt" && ! -e "home/usr/file-B.txt") { print "Only File-A.txt present"; last SWITCH; }
        if (-e "home/usr/file-A.txt" && ! -e "home/usr/file-B.txt") { print "Only File-B.txt present"; last SWITCH; }
        else { print "None of the file present"; last SWITCH }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ashish, Do you think it will be easier to implement in perl ? 
 
I want check if a files A or B are present in a directory. If none, either or both files are present in the directory, it should be informed to the user.

Comment: In such case where not much of working is required, both implementation would be nearly same.

Comment: @chepner , yash asked for it in the comments. However respecting what you said, I shall remove it.

Comment: My apologies: i just noticed perl is mentioned in the comment on the question.

Comment: Thanks @Ashish, the perl code is giving the correct output but it doesn't prints the files name. I also want the name of the files which exists.

Comment: See the edit.. `!` operator ensures for absence of any file.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the trick :

```
if test -e "/home/usr/file-A.txt" ||  -e "/home/usr/file-B.txt"; then 
 echo "INFO: the required file is present" 
else
 echo "INFO: file was not found"
fi
```

The `[` operator is just shorthand for test.

The `-o` is used as the `OR` operator.

Comment: `-o` is obsolete and all but depreciated; use two `test` commands instead. `if test -e ... || test -e ...; then`.